# Laravel 4 db query , db::raw() error because of if

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
$data = DB::table('view_term_invoice')
            ->groupby('tenant_no')
            ->select(
                'tenant_no' , 
                DB::raw('count(distinct term_no) as term'),
                DB::raw('count(distinct invoice_no) as invoice_no'),
                //DB::raw("if(type_inv = 'M',count(distinct invoice_no),0) as invoice_m"),
                //DB::raw("if(type_inv = 'T',count(distinct invoice_no),0) as invoice_t"),
                DB::raw("sum(distinct grand_total) as grand_total")
            )
            ->get();
```

when i running this query on db::raw i got error because of `if()` inside `db::raw` 
when i running on phpmyadmin i got no issue ,
i don`t understand why suddenly i got this error

Comment: What `if()` statement inside of DB::raw? Can you please provide the exact error?

Comment: when i use DB::raw("if(type_inv = 'M',count(distinct invoice_no),0) as invoice_m") show runtime error on my browser

Comment: when i not use if in DB::raw() , it work , but when i use if it show runtime error on my browser

Comment: Can you please write error message ?

Comment: error that show in my browser RuntimeException

Comment: you can print complete query like this. $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
  $last_query = end($queries);
  print_r($last_query);exit; seems like sql DB::raw is correct check in your db type_inv exists?

Comment: type_inv is exists , when i try again , probably the cause is ' ' , i try with DB::raw("if(type_inv = null,count(distinct invoice_no),0) as invoice_m") is working , but i want to put condition equal to 'M' for type_inv

Comment: From what I see you have too many parentheses in your query. There are 2 opening and 3 closing ones.